# trying to validate a login from android json post with a status code

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to validate a login using the below code. My challenge is to how get a response of 200 status code and if yes display the welcome screen. This is my code attempt but it has no status to confirm is the post is successful thereafter take the next action.

```
public  void executeLoginValidation() {
        Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();

        comment.put("email", loginActivityEmail.getText().toString());
        comment.put("password", loginActivityPassword.getText().toString());
        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
        makeRequest("http://localhost:88/API/web/app_dev.php/validatelogin/", json);
    }

    public static HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please how can I modify the above form post code to return a status code and thereafter take the necessary step fron login screen

Comment: Try this http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-status-code

Comment: Get the status code from response(`HttpResponse`) with `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`

Answer (score 0):

As the other said before me, try getting the status code from the HttpResponse:

```
public  void executeLoginValidation() {
    Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
    comment.put("email", loginActivityEmail.getText().toString());
    comment.put("password", loginActivityPassword.getText().toString());
    String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
    HttpResponse response = makeRequest("http://localhost:88/API/web/app_dev.php/validatelogin/",json);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();    
    if(statusCode == 200){
        showSplashScreen();
    }else{
        //ErrorHandling
    }
}
```